# MySQL Query to display information in certain way

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a difficult time trying to do a query to display results in a certain way.
What I need is to display all user answers in a single row per user, I cannot concatenate all the answers because my program needs to access
the result of every answer and for what I understand concatenation
will return a string.

This is how the tables are defined:

Here's where a user's information is stored.
Users

```
+------+---------+-------------+
| u_id | email   | name        |
+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | bob@b   | bob         |
|    2 | r@e.com | sam         |
|    3 | ra@se   | steve       |
|    4 | tv@we   | rob         |
|    5 | tr@sd   | ted         |
|    6 | qw@as   | john        |
+------+---------+-------------+

Questions
+------+---------+-------------+
| q_id | question_name         |
+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | Age range?            |
|    2 | Do you use Amazon?    |
|    3 | Do you use Facebook?  |
|    4 | Interested in toys?   |
+------+---------+-------------+
```

These are the possible answers a user can choose.

```
Option_Choices
+------+---------+-------------+
|oc_id | opt_choice_name       |
+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | YES                   |
|    2 | NO                    |
|    3 | 18-24 Years           |
|    4 | 25-35 Years           |
|    5 | Very Interested       |
|    6 | Not Interested        |
+------+---------+-------------+
```

Here's where a question is related with every possible
answer for that specific question.

```
Question_Options
+------+---------+-------------+
|qo_id | q_id    | oc_id       |
+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | 1       | 3           | // Age range?: 18-24
|    2 | 1       | 4           | // Age range?: 25-35
|    3 | 2       | 1           | // Do you use Amz? Yes
|    4 | 2       | 2           | ...
|    5 | 3       | 1           | ...
|    6 | 3       | 2           | ...
|    7 | 4       | 5           | ...
|    8 | 4       | 6           |
+------+---------+-------------+
```

Here's where the answers given by every user are stored.

```
Answers
+------+---------+-------------+
| a_id | u_id    | qo_id       |
+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | 1       | 2           |
|    2 | 1       | 4           |
|    3 | 1       | 6           |
|    4 | 1       | 7           |
|    1 | 2       | 1           |
|    2 | 2       | 3           |
|    3 | 2       | 6           |
|    4 | 2       | 8           |
|    1 | 3       | 2           |
|    2 | 3       | 4           |
|    3 | 3       | 5           |
|    4 | 3       | 8           |
+------+---------+-------------+
```

What I need now is to build a query to display the information
in a similar manner as this:

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
| email   | Age range?  | Use Amazon? | Use FB?     | Interested in toys? |
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
| bob@b   | 18-24 Years |    YES      |    NO       | Very Interested     |
| r@e.com | 25-35 Years |    NO       |    YES      | Not Interested      |
| ra@se   | 25-35 Years |    NO       |    YES      | Not Interested      |
| tv@we   | 18-24 Years |    YES      |    YES      | Not Interested      |
| tr@sd   | 18-24 Years |    YES      |    NO       | Not Interested      |
| qw@as   | 25-35 Years |    YES      |    YES      | Very Interested     |
+------+---------+--------------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

But using just JOIN I get something like this"

```
+---------+----------------+-----------------+
| email   | question_name  | opt_choice_name |
+---------+----------------+-----------------+
| bob@b   | Age range?     |  18-24 Years    |
| bob@b   | Use Amazon?    |    YES          |
| bob@b   | Use FB?        |    NO           |
| bob@b   | Inter in toys? |Very Interested  |
| r@e.com | Age range?     |  25-35 Years    |
| r@e.com | Use Amazon?    |    NO       |
| r@e.com | Use FB?        |    YES          |
| r@e.com | Inter in toys? | Not Interested  |

   ...         ...               ...
+---------+----------------+-----------------+
```

I tried using pivots with a query like this:

```
SELECT u.email,
(CASE q.question_name WHEN q_id = 1 THEN oc.opt_choice_name ELSE 0) AS 'Age_Range',
(CASE q.question_name WHEN q_id = 2 THEN oc.opt_choice_name ELSE 0) AS 'Amazon',
(CASE q.question_name WHEN q_id = 3 THEN oc.opt_choice_name ELSE 0) AS 'FB',
(CASE q.question_name WHEN q_id = 4 THEN oc.opt_choice_name ELSE 0) AS 'Toys'
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Ansers a ON u.u_id = a.u_id
INNER JOIN Question_Options qo ON a.qo_id = qo.qo_id
INNER JOIN Questions q ON qo.q_id = q.q_id
INNER JOIN Option_Choices oc ON qo.oc_id = oc.oc_id
GROUP BY u.email
```

But I'm getting mixed results.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

I tried using MAX

```
SELECT u.email,
MAX( CASE q.question_name WHEN q.question_id = 1 THEN oc.option_choice_name ELSE 0 END) AS 'AgeRange',
MAX( CASE q.question_name WHEN q.question_id = 2 THEN oc.option_choice_name ELSE 0 END) AS 'Amazon',
MAX( CASE q.question_name WHEN q.question_id = 3 THEN oc.option_choice_name ELSE 0 END) AS 'FB',
MAX( CASE q.question_name WHEN q.question_id = 4 THEN oc.option_choice_name ELSE 0 END) AS 'toys',
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Answers a ON u.u_id = a.u_id
INNER JOIN Question_Options qo ON a.qo_id = qo.qo_id
INNER JOIN Questions q ON qo.q_id = q.q_id
INNER JOIN Option_Choices oc ON qo.oc_id = oc.oc_id
GROUP BY u.email
```

But the results I'm getting are like:

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
| email   | Age range?  | Use Amazon? | Use FB?     | Interested in toys? |
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
| bob@b   | YES         |    YES      |    NO       |          NO         |
| r@e.com | YES         |    YES      |    YES      | YES                 |
| ra@se   | YES         |    YES      |    YES      | YES                 |
| tv@we   | YES         |    YES      |    YES      | YES                 |
+------+---------+--------------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Tabulating the result is a UI function, not a database function (at least not for mysql).

Comment: I agree. Just because you can, it doesn't mean you should (although sticking MAX in there will fix it! E.g. MAX(CASE...))

Comment: @Strawberry I tried before using MAX with no success

Comment: Hm, well consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) and I'm sure someone will show you.

Comment: @thebjorn please forgive my ignorance since I don't know anything about performance but isn't faster to return a table with all the data organized so the program can used it directly than use the program to do it so? I mean, for large amount of data. Thanks

Comment: @Strawberry I just posted an edit with the results using MAX

Comment: No. Not really. The application layer has to do a certain amount of work processing the array anyway, so it's not going to make any difference - except that you lose flexibility and scalability!

Comment: @Strawberry As you can see in the result table that I posted I'm not getting the right values for questions such as Age Range and Interested in Toys. According to my question_options table for Age Range, for instance, the acceptable answers are either 18-24 Years or 25-35 Years

Comment: @Sebastian no, you get fastest performance if the database layer performs well-optimizable queries, returning only the necessary data. Trying to format the data according to one single output format only means that you'll lose generality of the data, which, if we're talking about heavy usage scenarios, will destroy your database's cache. You should instead use a different server (either a UI server and/or a data-layer server) to tabulate your data in a form that is convenient for creating html.

Comment: @thebjorn Thanks, I'll follow you advice and use the code process to info and get the answers the way I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you could do this with MySQL, but it's not that efficient because MySQL indexes rows not columns.

> Indexes are used to find rows with specific column values quickly.
>   Without an index, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read
>   through the entire table to find the relevant rows. The larger the
>   table, the more this costs.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

The way most people would approach this is to enumerate all of the questions with a `JOIN` such as you have:

```
+---------+----------------+-----------------+
| email   | question_name  | opt_choice_name |
+---------+----------------+-----------------+
| bob@b   | Age range?     |  18-24 Years    |
| bob@b   | Use Amazon?    |    YES          |
| bob@b   | Use FB?        |    NO           |
| bob@b   | Inter in toys? |Very Interested  |
| r@e.com | Age range?     |  25-35 Years    |
| r@e.com | Use Amazon?    |    NO       |
| r@e.com | Use FB?        |    YES          |
| r@e.com | Inter in toys? | Not Interested  |

   ...         ...               ...
+---------+----------------+-----------------+
```

And then in your PHP you would do something like (*disclaimer: untested code*):

```
$i = 0;
echo "<table><tr><th>Age range?</th><th>Use Amazon?</th><th>Use Facebook?</th><th>Interested in Toys?</th></tr><tr>";
foreach ($results as $column) {
    echo "<td>".$column."</td>"; 
    if ($i != 0 && $i % 4) // Just arbitrarily chose 4, but it would be however many columns you have
        echo "</tr><tr>";

    $i++;
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll do it like that, using the php to get the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is create temporary tables separately for Every question and finally Create one mysql query to get all data horizontally at once.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm